# pythonモジュールのシンボルを指定したものだけ公開したい

Tags: python

以下のようなモジュールを定義したとします。

```
# libmod.py
import os

def get_cwd():
    os.getcwd()
```

利用者はこれをインポートしますが、IDE等の補完候補にlibmod.pyがimportしているosを表示したくないのです。

```
from libmod import os # <= osはlibmodの実装に使っているだけなので候補に出したくない
```

ドキュメントをしっかり作成しておけば問題ないと思うのですが、そうではない場合、利用者側にとってどれがこのモジュールが提供する機能なのか判断しづらいように思います。

パッと思いつくのは実装用のモジュールと、公開用のモジュールを別にする方法です。

```
# _libmod.py
import os

def get_cwd():
    os.getcwd()

# libmod.py
from ._libmod import get_cwd

# app.py
from libmod import get_cwd
```

ただ、この方法だとファイル数が2倍になってしまい面倒です。何かスマートな解決方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: (ja. じゃない) stackoverflow での類似の質問: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36015605/3026489

Comment: あまりスマートな解決案ではないですが、ファイルのトップレベルで `import` せず、使用する関数内で随時 `import` するという方法も考えられますね。

Comment: そうですね。しかしソースが乱雑になりすぎるので候補から外しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEが対応しているかどうかによると思いますが、たとえばモジュールに `__all__` を設定したら、自動補完の対象から除外してくれたりしないでしょうか。

https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

もしくは、上記のようなケースで os を候補に出さないIDEを利用するというのが一番良いのかもしれません。少なくとも手元の最新の PyCharm は 一番最初の例で os を候補には出しませんでした。

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

Comment: 確かにPyCharmだと__all__の指定に関係なく、モジュールのシンボルとfromでインポートしたシンボルだけが公開されますね。これは理想に近い動作です。本当はPython自体が__all__で指定したシンボルだけをエクスポートするという仕様であってくれればよかったのですが。

Comment: jedi-vimだと全部補完候補になってしまいますね。

Answer (score 1):

`os`を別名`_os`でimportすればprivate変数扱いになるのでIDEが出さなくなると思います
（IPython上でしか確認してないですが）

```
import os as _os
def get_cwd():
    return _os.get_cwd()
```

Comment: この方法も候補にはあったのですが、grep等での検索性が悪くなるのが難点ですね。